# Char array dimensioning confusion in Fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77, fortran-common-block

I have the following piece of code in my subroutine:

```
character    x*256 ,y*80
common /foo/ x     ,y(999)
```

Well, I did not actually write this. So I don't understant the dimensions here. Is `y` an 999 element wide array of 80 character long strings?

If so, how can I define this properly in Fortran 90, without the common block?

Comment: Are you asking how to declare a character array, or after a deeper understanding of the code fragment?  If the latter, then the short answer is: you're correct.

Comment: Maybe deeper understanding of char arrays. Because from C, what I am used to is that a string is a char array, and I have the pointer. What exactly happens here. What would happen if I said x(10), or y(10)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will first say that the code you have is "proper" Fortran 90, but I agree with wanting to move away from common blocks.

There is, essentially, nothing specific to the character nature of the declaration.  Whenever

```
<type> A
common /foo/ A(<size>)
```

is used there are two parts to the declaration of A, as well as the common association: the type and the dimension.  Ignoring the association, declaration of the dimension in the `common` statement is allowed and the above is like

```
<type> A
dimension A(<size>)
```

This is in turn the same as

```
<type>, dimension(<size>) :: A
```

Coming to the specific example, the type is a character of length 80.  Your non-common declaration would simply be

```
character(len=80), dimension(999) :: y
```

Indeed, then, `y` is a rank-1 array of size 999 of length-80 characters.  `y(10)` is a scalar length-80 character (the 10th element of the array `y`).

`x(10)` isn't correct syntax, as the `(10)` is array indexing, and `x` is a scalar.  For substrings a different indexing is required.  `x(10:10)` is the 10th character of the character variable `x`; `y(10)(10:10)` is the 10th character of the 10th element of the character array `y`.